# Error in displaying correct values form the previous screens

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am doing a application which is a small puzzle game.I am giving brief description of my App.

1.It contains Add details screen in that i kept 10 `TextFields`  and user need to enter data in that fields which i kept mandatory.After entering all the fields user need to choose one field and  need to press start Button which will advances to next labels Screens.

2.I kept 5 screens which contain labels in all the screens . For each screen if he user chosen field is there then he press YES or if user field is not there he will Press NO.Like this i kept for 5 screens .

3.According to user Where ever he pressed YES there i taken a boolean variable through that boolean variable i am righting the output of what user has chosen.

4.In the final screen i am displaying user chosen value in a label.

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    if (delegate.updateFirstView == NO && delegate.updateSecondView == NO && delegate.updateThirdView ==NO && delegate.updateFourthView == NO && delegate.updateFifthView == NO)
    {
        myLabel.text = @"Wrong Selection";
    }

    else if (delegate.updateFirstView == YES && delegate.updateSecondView == YES && delegate.updateThirdView == YES && delegate.updateFourthView == YES && delegate.updateFifthView == YES)
    {
        myLabel.text = delegate.fifthString;
    }

    else if (delegate.updateFirstView == YES && delegate.updateSecondView == YES && delegate.updateThirdView == YES && delegate.updateFourthView == YES)
    {
        myLabel.text = delegate.fourthString;
    }

    else if (delegate.updateFirstView == YES && delegate.updateSecondView == YES && delegate.updateThirdView == YES)
    {
        myLabel.text = delegate.thirdString;
    }

    else if (delegate.updateFirstView == YES && delegate.updateFourthView == YES && delegate.updateFifthView == YES) 
    {
        myLabel.text = delegate.tenthString;
    }

    else if (delegate.updateFirstView ==YES && delegate.updateSecondView == YES && delegate.updateFifthView ==YES) 
    {
        myLabel.text = delegate.eighthString;
    }

   else if (delegate.updateFirstView == YES && delegate.updateSecondView == YES)
    {
        myLabel.text = delegate.secondString;
    }

    else if (delegate.updateSecondView == YES && delegate.updateFourthView == YES) 
    {
        myLabel.text = delegate.sixthString;
    }

    else if (delegate.updateThirdView == YES && delegate.updateFourthView == YES) 
    {
        myLabel.text = delegate.seventhString;
    }

    else if (delegate.updateFourthView == YES && delegate.updateFifthView == YES) 
    {
        myLabel.text = delegate.ninthString;
    }

    else if (delegate.updateFirstView == YES) 
    {
        myLabel.text = delegate.firstString;
        NSLog(@"label name is %@",myLabel.text);
    }
```

whats happening here is if my  updateFirstView == YES  and i am comparing this. and for all it displays the same value.I want to know is there any Problem with my logic.

Help me where i am doing Mistakes.Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with your conditions:

```
 else if (delegate.updateFirstView == YES && delegate.updateSecondView == YES && delegate.updateThirdView == YES)
{
    myLabel.text = delegate.thirdString;
}

else if (delegate.updateFirstView == YES && delegate.updateFourthView == YES && delegate.updateFifthView == YES) 
{
    myLabel.text = delegate.tenthString;
}
```

Here if updateFirstView, updateSecondView and updateThirdView are "YES" then the label will display value of thirdString irrespective of the value of updateFifthView whether its YES or NO because program will never enter in that block as the condition prior to this block is true. Same is the case with other combinations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But what exactly i have to change here. Can u please tell.

Comment: Replace all the else. Put all the conditions in if structure only.

Comment: I tried Keeping IF before but there is no change. So i tried keeping else if.

Comment: You need to include all the values in each condition. Like if updateFirstView, updateSecondView and updateThirdView are "YES" in any of your condition then include updateFourthView and updateFifthView also with values as NO in the condition.

Comment: ohh k. let me try and tell u result. Thanks!!